# Wrong file name in different servers

Tags: java, glassfish

I've got an aplication that allows users to download some files. I run it on VMware vFabric tc Server Developer Edition v2.9 (default server in STS) and everything is fine. But now my server is GlassFish, so file name becomes wrong. 
For example - ***30-60 от 19.01.2015.txt***

Firefox:30-60_ (with no extension)

Chrome: 30-60_    _19.01.2015.txt

What is wrong? The code:

```
response.setHeader(
                "Content-disposition",
                "attachment;filename="
                        + BufferUtil.getEncoded(distributionService.get(id)
                                .getTitle(), request) + ".txt");
response.setContentType("text/xml, text/plain");
```

BufferUtil.getEncoded:

```
public static String getEncoded(String text, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("user-agent");
        boolean isInternetExplorer = (userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") > -1);
        text=text.replace(' ', '_');

        try {
            byte[] fileNameBytes = text
                    .getBytes((isInternetExplorer) ? ("windows-1250")
                            : ("utf-8"));
            String dispositionFileName = "";
            for (byte b : fileNameBytes) {
                dispositionFileName += (char) (b & 0xff);
            }
            return dispositionFileName;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ence) {
            ence.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the filename contain any non-ASCII characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
java.net.URLEncoder.encode(distributionService.get(id).getTitle() + ".txt", "UTF-8")
```

instead of

```
BufferUtil.getEncoded(distributionService.get(id)
                            .getTitle(), request) + ".txt");
```

Comment: Firefox shows `%D0%BE%D1%82` instead of text(not ASCII). Also Chrome uses the same approach for few symbols like `(` or `)`.

Comment: Although not universal, some modern browsers may comply with RFC6266, which states that the content disposition header containing UTF-8 characters can be specified as in the following example:   Content-Disposition: attachment;
                          filename="EURO rates";
                          filename*=utf-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates